# How to answer "Will you be able to finish the job this week?"

Tags: grammar

which of the following answers to the question: "Will you be able to finish the job this week?" is appropriate,

1. I can't say it.
2. I don't expect so.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "appropriate".  They quite clearly have different meanings.  Which meaning do you want to express?  Why is there a problem for you?  Why only these two responses instead of the simpler "Yes" or "No".